# OR Formula in Word document not returning a value

Tags: excel-formula, ms-word

I am working on a document where I need to be able to test multiple options in an if statement to see if one of them are true to decide if a paragraph displays on the document. I have been trying to figure out why my OR formula is not returning a value for me to test and I am not sure why it is not showing anything when it is updating.

I have inserted a field and added a formula within that field that I am hoping will work with my If statement to show the proper paragraph contens.

When I use an Or statement, even one as simple as { OR(1=1) } and update and toggle the field I get no result. From what I have read I should get a 1 or a 0, but I don't seem to get either of these results. The line just ends up blank. When I test it with my If formula it always shows the false result, even when the Or contains a true result.

The formula I am currently working with is:
    { IF{ OR("$event.eventType.name}" = "Birthday", "$event.eventType.name}" = 
    "Conference" } "Yes" "No" }

If I update and toggle the Or field it shows blank, no result either true or false, and makes the If formula show as false event on results where it should show true. As I mentioned above I even tried setting it to 1=1 and still could not get it to show as true. Not sure if there is something I am missing in working with the formula.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your post what $event.eventType.name is. Presumably it's a field generated by an Addin. In that case, you should be able to use something like:

{IF{={IF{$event.eventType.name}= "Birthday" 1 0}+{IF{$event.eventType.name}= "Conference" 1 0}# 0}> 0 "Yes" "No"}

or:

{={IF{$event.eventType.name}= "Birthday" 1 0}+{IF{$event.eventType.name}= "Conference" 1 0} \# "'Yes',,'No'"}

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Nor is it practical to add them via any of the standard Word dialogues. The spaces represented in the field constructions are all required. If your fields are a kind of mergefield, you'll need to insert 'MERGEFIELD ' at the start of each one, thus:

{MERGEFIELD $event.eventType.name}